# Reshape numpy array to contain logical blocks of values from original array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

My google-fu has failed me!

I have a numpy array as follows:

```
    0     1     2     3
  ------------------------
0 | 100   110   120   130   
1 | 140   150   160   170
2 | 180   190   200   210
3 | 220   230   240   250
4 | 260   270   280   290
5 | 300   310   320   330
6 | 340   350   360   370
7 | 380   390   400   410
8 | 420   430   440   450
```

The shape of which is `(9, 4)`. I want to reshape the above array to the following `(6, 6)` array:

```
    0     1     2     3     4     5
  -------------------------------------
0 | 100   110 | 140   150 | 180   190
1 | 120   130 | 160   170 | 200   210
  -------------------------------------
2 | 220   230 | 260   270 | 300   310
3 | 240   250 | 280   290 | 320   330
  -------------------------------------
4 | 340   350 | 380   390 | 420   430
5 | 360   370 | 400   410 | 440   450
```

I'm able to do it with 2 `for` loops and some conditions. Is there a better way to achieve the same result using `numpy.reshape` in a single line of code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it is a `(3, 3)` array of `(2, 2)` arrays, so first reshape it inti a `(3, 3, 2, 2)` array.

Then transpose it so the axises are right for recombining it into a `(6, 6)` array:

```
a.reshape(3, 3, 2, 2).transpose([0,2,1,3]).reshape(6,6)
```

Comment: This creates additional dimensions. Is there a way to get the shape to be (6,6) rather than (3,3,2,2)?

Comment: The lines you drew are additional dimensions. Or do you want to re-concatenate it to become a `(6, 6)` array again?

Comment: The lines were only for illustration. Is there a way to re-concatenate it to become a (6,6) array? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Now transpose some axes, and reshape. Experiment.  `transpose(...,[0,2,1,3])` is my first guess.

Comment: `a.transpose([0,2,1,3]).reshape(6,6)` worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar but perhaps more intuitive:

```
a = np.arange(36).reshape([9,4])
>>>
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27],
       [28, 29, 30, 31],
       [32, 33, 34, 35]])

b = np.hstack(np.column_stack(a.reshape([3,3,2,2])))
>>>
array([[ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  9],
       [ 2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 16, 17, 20, 21],
       [14, 15, 18, 19, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 28, 29, 32, 33],
       [26, 27, 30, 31, 34, 35]])
```